# Count hours from a string by PHP

Tags: php

I am in need of counting hours from a php string. I searched a lot but found no working answers and result!

```
$time = "9.00am-1.00pm & 2.00pm-6.00pm";
```

I need to extract $time & count all the hours totally.
If I print $time then the output should be: 8 hours

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you've tried a lot, you should show those attempts...otherwise people aren't going to help you here

Comment: How do those times get there to begin with? Just to be sure you are not in a XY problem here..

Comment: Can't it be done?

Comment: I'd approach it in the following way: Step 1 - Break your time string into groups/ranges. Step 2 - Break the groups down further and convert them into DateTime objects. Step 3 - compare the times and add them all up. As others have pointed out; you need to show what you've tried already

Comment: Can you explain little more.......

Comment: I don't know how to do it! Can you please break the string into datetime objects? And givve me the code? Please

Comment: How are you getting this string? Are you making it up? Where does it come from?

Comment: I want the result : 8 hours

Comment: @NayeemTanvir You are ignoring our questions, that try to help you. Also, *anything can be done*. But, give us a bit more then, *please gimma tha codez*

Comment: It comes from a database record

Comment: @NayeemTanvir Why are they not standard dates to begin with, in that case? If it's parsed into a database, you can also make them `Datetimes` right then.

Comment: Bro! I have genarated this timestamp for attendance system

Comment: Your problem is how you *save* your data then, to begin with! Don't just save strings and try to parse them after if unnecessary. - *"bro"*

Comment: @Nytrix has hit the nail on the head. You *could* learn how to convert your string into an hours total but you'd be correcting a mistake made elsewhere. Store the times in the DB properly

Comment: Ok I am describing: I am doing this for one's attendance in a day. Then I am dividing the time into two shifts (morning 9.00am-1.00pm and afternoon 2.00pm-6.00pm). Then how can I save these records to the database?

Comment: Either as 2 entries of 2 columns or 1 entry of 4 columns. Each being a full date/time

Comment: @NayeemTanvir please edit the question and describe it from table structure so some one can help you........

Comment: Yes, make a *seperate* column for *morning_start* ,*morning_end*,*afternoon_start*,*afternoon_end* with each the `Datetime` of those values you are passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, time values should not be stored into database as a complete string, but try this, dirty solution:

```
$date = "9.00am-1.00pm & 2.00pm-6.00pm";
$result = explode("&", $date);
$range1 = explode("-", $result[0]);
$time1 = new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime($range1[0])));
$time2 = new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime($range1[1])));
$diff1 = $time1->diff($time2);
$range2 = explode("-", $result[1]);
$time3 = new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime($range2[0])));
$time4 = new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime($range2[1])));
$diff2 = $time3->diff($time4);
$total_hours = ($diff1->h + $diff2->h);
echo $total_hours;
```

Output:

```
8
```

Now,as you can see you have the difference as a object:

```
var_dump($diff1);
var_dump($diff2);
```

Output:

```
object(DateInterval)[3]
public 'y' => int 0
public 'm' => int 0
public 'd' => int 0
public 'h' => int 4
public 'i' => int 0
public 's' => int 0
public 'weekday' => int 0
public 'weekday_behavior' => int 0
public 'first_last_day_of' => int 0
public 'invert' => int 0
public 'days' => int 0
public 'special_type' => int 0
public 'special_amount' => int 0
public 'have_weekday_relative' => int 0
public 'have_special_relative' => int 0

object(DateInterval)[6]
public 'y' => int 0
public 'm' => int 0
public 'd' => int 0
public 'h' => int 4
public 'i' => int 0
public 's' => int 0
public 'weekday' => int 0
public 'weekday_behavior' => int 0
public 'first_last_day_of' => int 0
public 'invert' => int 0
public 'days' => int 0
public 'special_type' => int 0
public 'special_amount' => int 0
public 'have_weekday_relative' => int 0
public 'have_special_relative' => int 0
```

And you have access to the values (hours,minutes, seconds) in this case to the hours,  for example using:

```
 public 'h' => int 4

 $diff1->h
```

Answer (score 0):

You have saved time in four column's i guess like that if that then do like this

```
//for moring
$my_str1    =   strtotime("9.00am");
$my_str2    =   strtotime("1.00pm");
$second    =   $my_str2-$my_str1; //get second
$minutes = $second/60; //get minutes
$morning =  $minutes/60; //get hour
```

do it same for evening

```
 //for evening
$my_str3    =   strtotime("2.00pm");
$my_str4    =   strtotime("6.00pm");
$second1    =   $my_str4-$my_str3; //get second
$minutes1 = $second1/60; //get minutes
$evening =  $minutes1/60; //get hour
```

then sum morning and evening

```
$hour = $morning-$evening;
```

Comment: Don't feed the *fish*.. people need to try something by themselves.